# 2-pass batch video encoding using ffmpeg and/or python

Tags: windows, ffmpeg, batch, python, video-conversion

I have a large set of video files I would like to encode to smaller files on a Windows machine.

I want to use a 4K constant video bitrate and copy the audio.  I've settled on using 2-pass FFmpeg to get the best quality video, using this specific bitrate, and I've written a batch file that works, unless there is more than one video to convert:

```bat
for %%a in (*.mp4 *.mkv) do ffmpeg -y -i ^"%%a^" -c:v libx264 -b:v 4000k -preset fast -pass 1 -an -f mp4 NUL && ^

for %%a in (*.mp4 *.mkv) do ffmpeg -i ^"%%a^" -c:v libx264 -b:v 4000k -preset fast -pass 2 -c:a copy ^"converted/%%~na.mp4^"
```

- When I add additional video files to the directory, this command attempts to run the first pass on each video, deleting the previous first pass before moving on to the second pass for all the videos, thus defeating the purpose of two passes.

I'm relatively new to Python but I was thinking it might be easier to achieve this via Python.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Windows 10 64-bit

2-pass video encoding using cmd and ffmpeg using a 4K constant video bitrate and copy the audio.

Download 1MB sample .mkv file from [appsloveworld.com](https://www.appsloveworld.com/sample-mkv-video-sample-mkv-files/) - [SampleVideo_1280x720_1mb.mkv](https://docs.google.com/uc?export=download&id=1zbL3LoO84b54oEqYMuLX8S7kKlduG1b_)

CMD:

```
if not exist converted (md converted)
for %g in (*.mp4 *.mkv) do (
ffmpeg -y -i "%g" -c:v libx264 -b:v 4000k -preset fast -pass 1 -an -f mp4 NUL
ffmpeg -i "%g" -c:v libx264 -b:v 4000k -preset fast -pass 2 -c:a copy "converted\%~ng.mp4"
)
rem delete ffmpeg temp files
del ffmpeg2pass*
exit /b
```

Script:

```
if not exist converted (md converted)
for %%g in (*.mp4 *.mkv) do (
ffmpeg -y -i "%%g" -c:v libx264 -b:v 4000k -preset fast -pass 1 -an -f mp4 NUL
ffmpeg -i "%%g" -c:v libx264 -b:v 4000k -preset fast -pass 2 -c:a copy "converted\%%~ng.mp4"
)
rem delete ffmpeg temp files
del ffmpeg2pass*
exit /b
```

Two-pass batch convert .mp4 and .mkv 2-pass batch convert .mp4 and .mkv using cmd and ffmpeg.

Comment: Perfect!!! Thank you so much!!!

Answer (score 0):

in case anyone was looking for a full python implementation:

```python
import ffmpeg

def abr_vbr_1st_pass(inputPath, params):

    params.update({
                    'maxrate': params['b:v'],
                    'bufsize': params['b:v'] * 2,
                    'pass': 1,
                    'f': 'null'
                    })
    ffInput = ffmpeg.input(inputPath)
    ffOutput = ffInput.output('pipe:', **params)
    ffOutput = ffOutput.global_args('-loglevel', 'error')
    std_out, std_err = ffOutput.run(capture_stdout=True)

    return params

def abr_vbr_2nd_pass(inputPath, outputPath, params):

    params.update({
                    'pass': 2,
                    'f': 'mp4'
                    })
    ffInput = ffmpeg.input(inputPath)
    ffOutput = ffInput.output(
                              outputPath,
                              **params
                              )
    ffOutput = ffOutput.global_args('-loglevel', 'error')
    ffOutput.run(overwrite_output=True)

intputPath = '/path/to/source/media.mkv'
outputPath = '/path/to/output/media.mp4'

params =    {
            'threads': 4,
            'c:v': 'libx264',
            'c:a': 'copy',
            'f': 'mp4',
            'b:v': 3000000
            }

params = abr_vbr_1st_pass(inputPath, params)
abr_vbr_2nd_pass(inputPath, outputPath, params)
```